# Github: How do I setup email notification for any merge in my master branch

Tags: github

I am using GitHub and dealing with master branch and multiple release & feature branches. I know that, I can setup the email notification under settings of the repo. But this notification applies to all the repo. In my case, I just want to limit only for master branch.

How do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [GitHub Action](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions), with:

- the [`on.<push|pull_request>.<branches|tags>`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestbranchestags) to trigger said action only on `master`
- a plugin like [`peter-evans/sendgrid-action`](https://github.com/peter-evans/sendgrid-action) to send email with [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/).

That way, you get more control over the notification you want to send.